# Downloading files using Prompt and cURL

Tags: windows, macos, curl, download

> **Noob Alert !!**

Hi everyone,

I am here asking myself **" Is there some way to download a file from prompt on Windows using a command line tool like cURL ? "**. Let me explain, on MacBook *( it maybe works on any Unix OS, but I just had experience on Mac OS )* I can download (almost) anything from World Wide Web using curl like this :

```
curl 'http://www.linkforfile.com/file.extension'
```

I don't know how it really works, so for me it magically appears on my computer beautiful for my happiness. Cutting off all the boring story I am trying to download and run a file (a C code file for example) on Windows and it can works if I write : `curl -L -o 'file' 'linkforfile' && ./file`

But it's too easy to do, and I'm afraid thats not going to work so well. So I want to really know if cURL works natively or exist other command line tool to transfer data on Windows ?

Comment: cURL is available for Windows (both 32 and 64 bit). Command will likely be different as windows normally uses `/` instead of `-` for options.

Answer (score 1):

cURL doesn't work natively in Windows, this is a library tool so useful with command-line to provide transfer data with URL syntax. For download a file and execute it:

> curl -L -o "file path" internet_adress & path_file

But natively you can use powershell, you can create an script with extension .ps1 and for your task put this:

> $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
>   $client.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com",
>   "C:\users\user\file.html")

After execute the file with powershell (right-click -> execute with powershell) and enjoy it.